# How can I store key in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

Here is My code :

```
function addtocart(id,price) {
    var qty = $("#txt_qty" + id).val();
    var qty1 = new Array();
if (qty == '' || qty == 0) {
    alert('Please Enter Quantity');
    $("#txt_qty" + id).focus();
    return false;
}
if (qty != '' && type != '') {
    proid.push(id);
    var text = 'qty'+id+'='+qty;
    var keyValuePair = text.replace(/ /g,'').split('=');
    qty1.push([keyValuePair[0]] = [keyValuePair[1]]);
}
```

I need to store key in `qty1` array,I have already value called `qty`

How can i dynamically store key in `qty1` array

I am trying above attempt but not succeeded

Can anybody help me

Comment: Which array structure you want

Comment: what exactly you want to store? why ` qty1.push([keyValuePair[0]] = [keyValuePair[1]]);` assigning second value to first?

Comment: i need to store key and value pair so

Answer (score 0):

If you got already data value for `keyvaluepair[0]` and `keyvaluepair[1]`, then try use this :

```
var myObj = {}; // declare obj container
myObj[keyvaluepair[0]] = keyvaluepair[1]; // set key and value based on your variable
qty1.push(obj); // finally push obj into your qty1(array) variable
```

This is just an alternative, you can try use the solution provided by **@Disha V.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You need to set value against specific key, see below code. Also define new map like belwo

```
var qty1 =  new Object();//create new map and not array

qty1[keyValuePair[0]] = keyValuePair[1];
```

to read value again from map use below code

```
var value =  qty1[keyValuePair[0]];
```

Answer (score -1):

Associative array (name index) are treated as object in javascript/jquery. So you can use like this

```
var qty1= {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"};
var test = qty1.key1;             // "value1" will be returned
```

Or you can use array like this but it will be converted in object as above

```
var qty1= [];
qty1["key1"] = "value1";
qty1["key2"] = "value2";
qty1["key3"] = "value3";
var test = qty1[0];             // qty1[0] will return undefined
var test2 = qty1.key1;          // "value1" will be returned
```